# Pandas dictionary with two or multiple keys

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
Location    Test No.    Type    Value.1 Value.2
M-1         Test1       A       0.020   2.912
M-1         Test2       B       0.072   20.21
M-1         Test3       A       0.010   4.888
M-1         Test4       C       0.045   9.461
M-2         Test1       B       0.020   2.912
M-2         Test2       B       0.072   20.21
M-2         Test3       C       0.010   4.888
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary using first and second columns as keys. I think, I need a dictionary that looks like this:

```
Location    Test No.    Type    Value.1 Value.2
M-1         Test1       A       0.020   2.912
            Test2       B       0.072   20.21
            Test3       A       0.010   4.888
            Test4       C       0.045   9.461
M-2         Test1       B       0.020   2.912
            Test2       B       0.072   20.21
            Test3       C       0.010   4.888
```

so that when I call a location I can get access to values based on Test No. (second key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df = df.set_index(["Location", "Test No."]) # Columns  for dict keys
df_dict = df.to_dict("index") # Turn into dict`

Comment: Works as I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

You have pandas dataframe , you just stack with it

```
df=df.set_index(['Location','TestNo.'])
df
Out[298]: 
                 Type  Value.1  Value.2
Location TestNo.                       
M-1      Test1      A    0.020    2.912
         Test2      B    0.072   20.210
         Test3      A    0.010    4.888
         Test4      C    0.045    9.461
M-2      Test1      B    0.020    2.912
         Test2      B    0.072   20.210
         Test3      C    0.010    4.888
df.loc[('M-1','Test1')]
Out[299]: 
Type           A
Value.1     0.02
Value.2    2.912
Name: (M-1, Test1), dtype: object
```

Comment: This works very well. Didn't cross my mind just using the data frame. Merci :)

Comment: @Bob yw~ :-) since the df can carry more info :-)